# Progress Dialog for AsyncTask - Android issues(Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application)

Tags: android

```
public class ServiceLogin extends Service {

    public static boolean startService = false;

    UserHelper userHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e("Service", "=============Created");
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            userHelper=new UserHelper(this);
        }
        startService = true;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Service", "=============onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Service", "=============Destroy");
        //startService = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Service", "=============Unbind");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        System.out.println("Service is running outside method");
        if (startService == true) {
            System.out.println("Service is running");
            SendData login= new SendData(this);
            login.execute();
        }
    }
    private class SendData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String responsefromserver = null;
        String loginemail=null;
        String loginpassword=null;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        public SendData(ServiceLogin login) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(login);
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

                dialog.setMessage("Login, please wait...");
                dialog.show();

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            loginemail= AmrMethods.getDefaults("loginemail", ServiceLogin.this);
            loginpassword=AmrMethods.getDefaults("loginpassword", ServiceLogin.this);

            try {
                JSONArray ja1 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jsonarray = new JSONObject();

                jsonarray.put("user_email", loginemail);
                jsonarray.put("user_password", loginpassword);

                ja1.put(jsonarray);
                SendRequestLogin req = new SendRequestLogin();
                responsefromserver = req.sendRequsetBackground("userLoginAndroid", ja1);
                try {
                    String user_id,first_name,last_name,password,email,phone_no;

                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responsefromserver);
                    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++"+obj);
                    user_id=obj.getString("user_id");
                    first_name=obj.getString("first_name");
                    last_name=obj.getString("last_name");
                    password=obj.getString("password");
                    email=obj.getString("email");
                    phone_no=obj.getString("phone_no");
                    AmrMethods.setDefaults("user_id",user_id,getApplicationContext());

                    userHelper.saveLocation(user_id, first_name, last_name, password, email,phone_no);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            System.out.println(responsefromserver + "==============Response");
            if (responsefromserver == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check your Internet Connection or something went wrong",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(responsefromserver.equals("FAILURE")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Not Send",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success Fully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //userid=responsefromserver;
                //AmrMethods.setDefaults("userid",userid, ServiceLogin.this);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I have an error:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add
>   window -- token null is not for an application...

Can any one suggest me where i have done wrong.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: try adding these lines: if (dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } to your onPause(){} method in the activity or dismiss your dialog before you start next activity.

Comment: Hi, you cannot have access to UI elements in a service class, as the service is an background process. You can use AsyncTask in an Activity to show the login progress dialog.

Comment: I have done it before in another program its working but not in this code

Answer (score 0):

So a service is NOT the UI you have to use the observer pattern. Your activity have to register a listener in the service so that the service can inform the activity for special events (like start loading or finish loading).

Comment: I did it but facing the same problem...I think the error is showing for alertdialog.show();